# How can I use all my Gmail accounts in one place?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-account

I have a Gmail account that I use for my personal use, I am also now starting as a Gmail business user and can see I am already going to need another two email accounts.

I thought I would be able to pull those business accounts into my personal email, but I keep running into trouble, I thought it would be easier.

Is there a good, right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Google allows you to be logged in to at least 4 different Google accounts at once.

This allows you to keep each account logically separate yet easily manage them in one interface.

To add or switch accounts, click your icon in the top right corner and select Add account OR the account you want to switch to.

The link Jacob provided in comments is a good one.

Answer (score -1):

Try a client like Thunderbird.

I know that Google says you can use multiple accounts at once, but I keep hearing of things not working quite right due to caching etc.

And if you use a client, you can add multiple accounts to it and effectively be signed into all the accounts at the same time - and see them all at the same time.

I do this and regularly move messages between accounts using drag-and-drop.    Google's multiple sign-in just won't do this, because you see your accounts in different windows/tabs rather than all in the one place.   And I don't know any web-applications that have this feature.